# TextView margins not working inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, margin

I have this simple xml below. The problem is that none of the `layout_marginLeft`, `layout_marginRight`, `layout_marginTop` or `layout_marginBottom` work. But `layout_margin` works!

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" <-- does not work
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" <-- does not work
            android:text="This is a text!"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, I noticed that when I add an incomplete `layout_margin="0"` (without dp) it causes an error but the `marginLeft`, `marginRight`, etc. work! But then I have an error and it will not compile. What is going on here?!

Comment: Can you please add error here?

Comment: There is no error. The margins just don't show up in the design view or when I deploy the app. I have also tried invalidating caches - no help.

Comment: Try to use `layout_marginStart` instead of `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginEnd` instead of `layout_marginRight`.

Comment: Start and End attributes for margin introduces in Android API17, If your minSdk is greater than 17 then please your start and end for margin and padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit! Turns out I had this line in my `themes.xml`

```
<item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
```

which was messing up all the `layout_margin` calls. Removed the line and now the margins work correctly.